# How do I embed an Ember.js app in other sites without an iframe

Tags: javascript, ember.js, embed

I'm looking to embed an ember app into various sites using a javascript snippet. I have a widget that loads some posts from an api and I want to be able to load the app into a container div. I've researched all of the answers to similar questions on here, and all I can gleen is the basics of changing the rootElement and location as Ember docs say. But I can't find any clear help on the javascript to load the ember app on page, or any init stuff I need to do in the ember app itself.

We previously had something similar working with straight javascript with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywidget.com/javascripts/mywidget.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://mywidget.com/messages/list.jsonp?callback=mywidgetParseMessages&domain=" + window.location.hostname + "&relative_url=" + window.location.pathname;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

I'm clearly ember n00b here, so any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this page](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/)?

Comment: Maybe also checkout [ember-islands](https://github.com/mitchlloyd/ember-islands)

Comment: @Lux ember-islands looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!